# Как реализовать класс с отображением по ключу?

Tags: java

У меня есть два класса:

```
public class Category {

    private CategoryValue value;

    public CategoryValue getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(CategoryValue value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static enum CategoryValue {
        GENDER("GENDER"),
        INCOME("INCOME");

        private String value;

        CategoryValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}

public class Segment {

    private Category category;
    private SegmentValue value;

    public SegmentValue getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(SegmentValue value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public static enum Gender implements SegmentValue {
        MALE("MALE"),
        FEMALE("FEMALE");

        private String value;

        Gender(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static enum Income implements SegmentValue {
        A("A"),
        B("B"),
        C("C");

        private String value;

        Income(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Мне нужно реализовать класс Target, в котором будет лежать `Map<Category, Segment>`
Соответственно, надо сделать так, чтобы задавая ключ Category (например GENDER), то в сегментах должны лежать либо "MALE", либо "FEMALE" - как это сделать?

Comment: Может быть из-за того что слишком поздно, но лично у меня извилины путаются от таких конструкций. Может быть вы можете сформулировать задачу как-то иначе? Я имею ввиду, описать задачу для решения которой, вам понадобилось писать эти 2 класса.

Comment: Перевожу:
есть переменные "а" и "б" - это энумы в одном классе (класс - переменные).
Есть другой класс (назовем класс значения)- там лежат два энума: один энум - возможные значения переменной "а", другой - возможные значения "б"

Вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы можно было сделать Мар<Переменные, значения> так, чтобы задавая ключ, т.е. пихая в мапу переменну (скажем "а") значение должно быть из возможных значений переменной

Comment: > есть переменные "а" и "б" - это энумы в одном класс

Нет, нет, нет! Вы скажите ЧТО вы хотите сваять? Какую задачу решить. В терминах предметной области. А то есть подозрение, что вы что-то в корне не так делаете ) Потому что, чтобы помочь вам "реализовать класс", надо понимать с чем мы имеем дело.

Comment: мне нужно сделать класс Target, в котором будет лежать Мар<Категория, Сегмент> - сделать абстракцию атомарного сегмента

Comment: Вы повторяете свой вопрос уже второй раз. Можете сформулировать что вам нужно? Вынесите энумы хотя бы в отдельные классы, а не делайте их внутренними.

Comment: Энумы вынес в отдельные классы.
да я уже описал, что мне нужно - нужно создать Мар<Категория, Сегмент> чего вам еще не хватает то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь, вам этот код поможет разобраться как пользоваться `enum`:

```
public class UsingEnums {

    // вы задаете нужные вам enumeration
    private static enum Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE
    }

    private static enum PayMethod {
        CASH, CARD
    }

    // задаем поля, каждое имеет тип соответсвующего ему enumeration
    private Gender gender = null;
    private PayMethod payMethod = null;

    // геттеры/сеттеры для полей
    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        if (null == gender) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        Gender g = null;
        try {
            g = Gender.valueOf(gender);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid gender value", e);
        }

        this.gender = g;
    }

    public PayMethod getPayMethod() {
        return payMethod;
    }

    public void setPayMethod(PayMethod payMethod) {
        this.payMethod = payMethod;
    }

    public void setPayMethod(String payMethod) {
        PayMethod pm = null;
        try {
            pm = PayMethod.valueOf(payMethod);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid gender value", e);
        }

        this.payMethod = pm;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return gender + "/" + payMethod;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create dummy bean
        UsingEnums u = new UsingEnums();

        // использование геттера и сеттера для параметра типа enum
        // по умолчанию уже позволяет фильтровать невалидные значения
        // потому что они не будут соответствовать типу enum
        u.setGender(Gender.MALE);
        u.setPayMethod(PayMethod.CARD);

        System.out.println(u);

        // change values using
        u.setGender("FEMALE"); // OK
        u.setPayMethod("CASH"); // OK

        System.out.println(u);

        try {
            u.setGender("both"); // FAIL
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("was unable to set gender:"
                    + e.getLocalizedMessage()
                    + ", one of the following expected: "
                    + Arrays.toString(Gender.values()));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам не нужен класс Segment. Вам не нужен класс Category. Хотите добавлять что-то в мапу:

```
Map<CategoryValue, SegmentValue> map = new HashMap<CategoryValue, SegmentValue>();
map.put(CategoryValue.GENDER, Income.A);
map.put(CategoryValue.INCOME, Gender.MALE);
```